# What matters most is your safety

Tags: free-relative-clauses, interrogatives

> (a) What other people think and say about us matters, a lot. ([NYT](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/09/28/opinion/sunday/learning-to-love-criticism.html?ref=opinion&_r=0))
>   (b) What matters most is your safety. ([Merriam-Webster’s Learners’ 4.d](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/what))

(a) seems to have a fused relative, equivalent to “The thing that (i) other people think and say __ (i) about us matters, a lot.” 
While there being no gap in (b), I would think that what-clause in (b) seems to be an interrogative clause; yet the dictionary says ‘what’ is equivalent to ‘the thing that.’ Is it, *What matters most*, a fused relative that has no gap? (Can this, a fused relative without any gaps, be possible at all?) Or is it a interrogative clause, for there's no gap?

Comment: Would it help you to note the the exact syntactic role of ***what*** is different in your two examples? If we recast #2 to the same form as #1, it becomes *"Your safety matters most"* (i.e. - there is no ***what***). Conversely, if we recast #1 to the format of #2 we get *"**What** matters a lot is **what** other people think and say about us"*. Does that perspective help you?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Very helpful explanation there! You should do more syntax stuff on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FumbleFingers put his finger on it: these are both fused relatives, but the initial term *what* plays different syntactic roles.

- In ‘What other people think and say about us’ *what* is the Object of *think and say*. Analysis speaks of a ‘gap’<sup>†</sup> because the Object has been displaced to the front of the clause from its canonical position after the verb.
- In ‘What matters most’ *what* is the Subject of *matters*. There is no ‘gap’ because the Subject already occupies its canonical position at the front of the clause.

You will find the same pattern in the analysis of bound relatives:

- The horrible things<sub>i</sub> **which**<sub>i</sub> other people say _<sub>i</sub> about us do matter.
- Your safety<sub>i</sub>, **which**<sub>i</sub> is what matters most, has been assured.

---

<sup>†</sup>There is, of course, no actual gap in the utterance: it is an artifact of the analysis being performed.